# Returning only 1 result, how can I return all?

Tags: php

I am currently building a **simple_html_dom.php** script and I am trying to parse all of the data and store it into one string so I can submit the data into my WordPress site, here's what I have so far.

```
$test = $html->find('.post img', 0);
$src = $test->plaintext;

if (strpos($src, '/wp-content/uploads/20') !== false) {
    print '<br>';
    $premade = '<img src="'.$src.'" class="data-m" />';
    print htmlspecialchars($premade);
}

$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( trim( $uej ) ),
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_content' => $premade,
    'post_category' => array(6),
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
```

This is returning only one result when I print it out, how can I make it so that all of the results are compiled into one string?

Comment: I'd guess the second parameter of simple_html_dom's `find` is the number/position of elements to return so maybe remove `0` or use `-1`. I find the documentation for that library terrible though so can't really help ya.

Comment: @user3783243 if I remove 0 it returns NO results'

Comment: Found the manual, it returns an array `Find elements by the CSS selector. Returns the Nth element object if index is set, otherwise return an array of object.` So iterate over it. ... or I think you didn't tag the library but that looks like simple_html_dom to me